# Laravel lumen is not saving right time zone

Tags: timezone, lumen

Everyone
I am new to Laravel Lumen Framework.I am using Laravel Lumen 5.4.7 and my PHP version is 7.0.I am getting the issue while saving time zone in database using Laravel Lumen web api.I have changed my local time zone in .env file

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/karachi
```

When i just echo this code

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

or this

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()
```

both lines of code returns me my current local time but when i save this timezone in database for "created_at" and "updated_at" fields.It saves wrong time zone.Why this is happening?I am using this line of code to save data in database

```
$order_data=array(
        'amount'=>35,
        'updated_at' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'created_at' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now()
    );
DB::table('orders')->insertGetId($order_data);
```

I have also tried this line of code to save data

```
DB::table('orders')->insert($order_data);
```

But still got wrong time zone in database in created_at and updated_at field.Then i also updated my code to use Elequont,for this purpose i have created a model named "Order" but still got wrong time zone in database.My Elequont code is following.

```
$order_data=array(
        'amount'=>35,
        'updated_at' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'created_at' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now()
    );   
Order::create($order_data);
```

I have tried too much to remove this issue.But not get any luck yet.Can anyone help me why Lumen is not saving current time zone in database?

Comment: Could you specify which timezone is saved in the database?

Comment: I am in Pakistan.And date('Y-m-d H:i:s') shows me my current local time.but it saves in database wrongly.I can't able to find which time zone is saving in database.Now  i echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').it shows me this time  2018-10-24 13:06:04 which is absolutely correct.But in database this time is saved 2018-10-24 06:06:04

Comment: Do you use mysql? If so, could you post the results of the following query: `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`?

Comment: Yes,I am using mysql.and have a look on this screenshot for Query result.[Query Result](http://prntscr.com/l9ry3d)

Comment: Have you tried using `config(['app.timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE')]);`?

Comment: No i haven't.How i use this?Means above save function i write this code?

Comment: You can put it anywhere in your application :)

Comment: i have used in this way in Model function `config(['app.timezone' =>env('APP_TIMEZONE')]); 
        return User::create($formdata);`

Comment: But no success :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', "UTC")` to your `config/app.php` and running `php artisan cache:clear` after that.

Also try adding `DB_TIMEZONE=+05:00` to your `.env` file (adjusted to your UTC offset of course)

Comment: In Laravel Lumen Framework config/app.php is not available :( :(.

Comment: @Shaniawan, it is :) you just have to take the default config from the vendor folder (`vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config`) and put it in your `config/app.php`, then you can make the changes.

Comment: Thanks Sven for your Support.But this way too doesnot work.I have copied vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/app.php file and create a new directory named as config in root directory and paste that file in new folder.Add `'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', "Asia/karachi")` in this file and use commad `php artisan cache:clear` and then save the data but no luck sir :( :(

Comment: This thing is working fine in Laravel 5.4 framework but not in Laravel Lumen Framework. :(

Comment: Thanks alot.That does the trick.Thanks alot for your Support :)